# How are foreign keys created and enforced in postgres?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

- When creating/inserting a foreign key relationship in Postgres what steps does the backend perform that ensure the referential integrity of my tables?
- How does Postgres know where the relevant foreign keys are in the many tables?

All of my searches just say how to implement and examples but not the nuts and bolts of the backend. If I wrote my own checks when inserting data would that be the same thing and as efficient as Postgres?

Postgres documentation is unsatisfying in its description:

> "In simplistic database systems this would be implemented (if at all)
> by first looking at the cities table to check if a matching record
> exists, and then inserting or rejecting the new weather records. This
> approach has a number of problems and is very inconvenient, so
> PostgreSQL can do this for you."

**Edit**: Nice book link I'm guessing will answer my question [The Internals of PostgreSQL](https://www.interdb.jp/pg/)

**Clarification**: I am not intending to write my own checks or triggers, I understand they will not be as good. The question is to glean details and a better understanding of optimizations.

Comment: 1) You did not spend much time searching the docs, see [Foreign Keys](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK), [pg_constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/catalog-pg-constraint.html)[Info schema FK](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/infoschema-referential-constraints.html), [Create table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html). 2) You don't want to do this yourself, the database will be much more efficient.

Comment: As to the backend they are created as triggers per [Trigger functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/functions-trigger.html).

Comment: Thanks for the links, but none of this answers the question of how the backend is performing these steps. Saying the database will be more efficient is basically my question, why?

Comment: Trigger functions seem to be the path of what I'm after so I'll dig more into that as well!

Comment: @CharlesCurt Because they can be micro-optimized by the dev team. Why there's not more details about the internals in the basic docs, because documentation is a promise to the user about how the software will behave. SQL is a [declarative language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_programming) specifically shielding you from the nuts and bolts. Exactly how Postgres does its work is an implementation detail and can change at any time. "*PostgreSQL can do this for you*" is accurate. You might find more detail on the [PostgreSQL Wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Main_Page).

Comment: The engine has access to the internal structures of the tablespaces, as well as caches and other data structures (such as WAL) that you cannot see from the external application. As a general rule, the engine use all kinds of dirty tricks to get the job done. On top of that, it's a team of seasoned developers that built this over a long period of time. I'm sure it's theoretically possible to do better, but I doubt I could do a better job in a similar time frame.

Comment: @Schwern That is a good resource thanks. Do you have an example of a "micro-optimized" function? Considering it an implementation detail bugs me, the fact that [pg_catalog](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalogs-overview.html) is so massive and I know nothing of the system architecture is not great. Yes, I could dig through it and the wiki for a few years but there has to be nice summary info out there.

Comment: @CharlesCurt "*Considering it an implementation detail bugs me*" get used to it; all good software hides the details, particularly declarative languages. You can search for blog and wiki posts, but if you want gory details I'd start by searching for a constraint error message [in the source code](https://github.com/postgres/postgres) and working backwards from there. Also look for pull requests about changing the constraint system.

Comment: FK's are implemented with system triggers that you don't want to touch. You are diving deep into the area of premature optimization. FK's are used successfully  on a daily basis across innumerable databases and tables in a performant manner. Your time would be better spent actually creating a database and populating it and then deal with issues if they arise. I will go out on a short limb and say you will, for the most part, not see issues with FK's. Decidedly less then if you try to implement them yourself.

Comment: I don't think asking about one level below "I call a function and it does what I want" is that far down the rabbit hole. I don't plan on making my own calls. I work with distributed systems and want to know more about Postgres as a system. Specifically about foreign keys due to our team doing very large inserts (millions to billions) into a Postgres DB I manage.

Comment: This is a great question and I'm curious myself about how foreign keys are implemented in postgres. Did you get any closer to finding that out?

Answer (score 0):

It is of course recommended to use foreign keys in the DB rather than writing any code in any trigger or backend. Let me explain the reasons:

1. You don't write any additional codes on backend or on triggers.
2. If the business logic ever changes, you won't have to make many changes to the code.
3. If you have to manually write foreign keys yourself, maybe you will have any bugs or you will forget to write checking foreign keys, but foreign keys on DB reliably always provides this check.
4. During migration, maybe someone will run a bulk insert on the DB from the outside your backend, or if someone (or DB admin) will be deleted data mistily, foreign keys on DB will strictly not allow this.